# Tag helpers not working in .NetCore 5.0 after migration from 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have upgraded my project from `3.1` to `.netcore` `5.0`. After doing that tag helpers asp-action and asp-controller not rendering while they were working on `3.1`, I have checked the `viewimport` file it has reference to `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` and my project also has this included in the framework but still not sure why it is not working.

[Rendered HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUjXb.png)

[Tag helper in .cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQmhg.png)

[taghelper reference in viewimport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjObV.png)

Comment: please add your code snippets as text not images

Comment: how did you upgrade your project? manual changes to project file and package updates? were there any changes made to startup?

Comment: I did manual update changed the target framework to 5.0 as per Microsoft documentation and updated entity other packages to compatible to 5.0, asp-for and other tag helper are working just asp-action and asp-controller doesn't. Tried to search online got nothing.

Comment: add that information (having done it manually/in reference to documentation) and add link to that documentation to your question please.

Comment: I followed these two documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio https://henriquesd.medium.com/migrating-an-application-from-net-core-3-1-to-net-5-9908655658c0

Comment: @CHETANSUTHAR add ```@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"``` with ```"``` and rebuild your project.

Comment: @PritomSarkar Tried no success.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue it was Multitenancy that was conflicting with the mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following operations may be useful to you.
1.Close all instances of Visual Studio.

2.Download and install the latest .NET Core SDK.

3.Open "Apps & features" (Add or remove programs)

4.Search for ".NET Core SDK" and uninstall all except the latest version (x64 and/or x86).

5.Reopen Visual Studio.
If it does not work, it may be a problem with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools, please run in the terminal:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools --prerelease
```

If it doesn't solve, delete your .vscode folder inside your user folder and install C# and other extensions again.After restart VS Code, everything works again.